# I would like to Convert a Byte to 3 digits in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, format, byte, digits

For example:

If the Byte value is `5`, I would like it to be displayed as `005`.

If the Byte value is `10`, I would like it to be displayed as `010`.

Basically, I always want 3 digits. `119` would remain `119`.

I'm aware of `.padleft`, but do not want to use an if statement. I tried `Format("D3")` with no luck.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using String.Format, you need to specify the index for the parameter, not just `D3`, so it would be something like this:

```
Dim r As Byte = 10
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:D3}", r))
```

Alternatively, you could just use `D3` into the ToString of r:

```
Dim r As Byte = 10
Console.WriteLine(r.ToString("D3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to specify the number of digits you want in the output:

```
Dim b As Byte = 5
Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:000}", b))
```

Or use this in the `.ToString` overload like this:

```
Debug.WriteLine(b.ToString("000"))
```

in both cases the output is `005`

Comment: I did try something similar, but my syntax appeared off. I will try it later this evening when I get home. Thank you!